# How to link array with a serial index to a dataframe with 2 keys?

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, pickle

I have a dataframe in Python that has my dataset features called **df_features**

```
University , Subject, F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6 
Melb         Math     4   3   9   2   5   5
Melb         Physics  3   3   2   3   4   3
Melb         English  6   7   6   8   7   3
Ottawa       Math     4   7   8   7   2   7
Ottawa       English  3   3   5   5   1   7
Ottawa       Med      1   5   3   3   1   7
Syd          Math     9   6   9   3   5   6
```

The key for this dataframe is 2 columns

```
University , Subject
```

I used this dataset in predicting values through a pre-saved model

```
loaded_model = pickle.load(open('E:\model.sav', 'rb'))

y_pred = loaded_model.predict(df_features)
```

Now **y_pred** is an array that has just an index

so it looks like this

```
0  Red
1  Blue
2  Green
3  Blue
4  Red
5  Red
6  Yellow
7  Red
8  Blue
```

How can I match each value in the **y_pred** array to its University and Subject in **df_features**?

Comment: Maybe I don’t understand something, but on what basis should there be a comparison? How should university names and colors be related?

Comment: @Paitor I am not asking to predict colours, my question is about joiing dataframe and array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer.

adding a new column in the dataframe and match it to the array should do that

the array is the prediction result of the dataframe.

Therefore, The order of the index is similar for both the dataframe and the array

```
df_features["Colour"] = y_pred
```